# C++/Ada Link Errors

Tags: c++, linker-errors, ada

I am not familiar with link errors at all so I was hoping someone could shed some light on these errors...

I am working with a Legacy Ada program. I am developing a C++ Extension in which the Ada will use a proxy to call the C++ functions. The C++ compiles cleanly without any warnings. However I am getting the following Undefined Symbol errors:

```
__nw__FUi
__walkback
__dl__FPv
```

The code base is as follows:

```
#include "cppProxy.h"
extern classHandler *classPtr;

void processData(void* ioBuffer)
{
   classPtr->processData(ioBuffer);
}
```

Header File:

```
#include "classHandler.h"
extern "C" void processData(void* ioBuffer);
```

classHandler.cpp

```
extern "C"
{
   classHandler* create()
   {
      return new classHandler;
   }
   void destroy(classHandler *p)
   {
      delete p;
   }
}

void processData(*ioBuffer)
{
   int idx;
   data = static_cast<int*>(ioBuffer);

   idx = (data[0] >> 16);
   returnData[idx] = data;
}
```

classHandler.h

```
class classHandler
{
   public:
     classHandler();
     ~classHandler();

    void processData(void* ioBuffer);
};

typedef classHandler classPtr;
typedef void destroy_t(classHandler*);
```

Now the objective is to have the C++ keep track of the object so I was trying to create a singleton that would then be called. Looking at the current state of the code I am trying to figure out where this is since I have done multiple changes trying to fix the linker error.

Overall I am wondering if this is truly a linking error or an issue with my class implementation. I am leaning towards the latter but still uncertain on how to resolve the issue.

Once again the design I am going for is as follows:

Implemented:
Ada calls the C++ to process data.
C++ parses the data and stores it locally.

Not Implemented:
Ada calls the C++ to retrieve the data.
C++ does a lookup and returns data array.

Any help would be appreciated on this since I am lost in my own code at the moment. Thanks!

EDIT1:

The Ada code is too robust but I know with certainty that that side is correct. As for the compiler, I am using Concurrent ANSI C/C++ compiler (PowerPC) – 5.4 (005). I CANNOT change compilers. The first two fragments are the proxy layer of the code. This is what the Ada portion uses to interface into the C++ code.

Comment: Where do the first two code fragments fit into the problem? What do you mean by “the Ada will use a proxy to call the C++ functions”? What is your Ada code? What operating system/compiler are you using?

Comment: `__nw__FUi` is the decorated name of `operator new(size_t)` and `__dl__FPv` is `operator delete(void*)`. They fail because you are not linking the C++ library, but you can just define them in your code. No idea about that weird `__walkback`, though.

Comment: Rodrigo I am not too familiar with this. Would it be including the libraries or doing something else?

Comment: @rodrigo, the Ada calls the C++ which invokes `operator new(size_t)` etc, so defining ones own version would be unlikely to work properly. If Sharki was using GCC, linking with `-lstdc++` might be the answer. I don’t know the Concurrent equivalent. Perhaps looking at how Concurrent links a pure C++ program (maybe, one which just calls the proxy code) would help.

Comment: @SimonWright: I don't see why defining `new` and `delete` operators would do harm, since they are undefined right now. Just `void * operator new(size_t n) { return malloc(n); } void operator delete(void * p) { free(p); }` (plus the relevant error management code) should fix these two errors.

Comment: What compiler are you using for the Ada sources?

Comment: Have you considered starting with a simpler problem, where you interface with a pure C library (so you don't have to worry about problems in more than one layer at a time)?

Comment: Interfacing between Ada and C is (at least technically) highly compiler specific.  Have you checked in the documentation for your Ada compiler, if it supports your specific C compiler version?  (Or if the C compiler emits object code which is binary compatible with a supported C compiler.)

Comment: Can you add the sequence of compilations you are using to compile with? Usually you will need to compile the packages / classes separately before binding & linking.